# ItemList error in SDTT: "All values provided for url must point to the same page"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to add the `ItemList` Schema.org markup on an article page that lists top 10 software with (external) links pointing to them.

When I tested the following JSON-LD markup on SDTT, I got the error message saying

> All values provided for `url` must point to the same page

I don't really understand why the individual list items should use the same URL?!

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "name": "Title of the page",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "image": "https://www.product-1.com/image",
        "URL": "https://www.product-1.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "image": "https://www.product-2.com/image",
        "URL": "https://www.product-2.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

I used a slightly different markup without the `"item": {` as put in https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings, but this time I'm getting an error message that says

> All values provided for `url` must have the same domain

Can you please help me solve this problem?

```json
{
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type":"ItemList",
  "name": "Title of the page",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "itemListElement":[
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":1,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "image": "https://www.product-1.com/image",
        "URL": "https://www.product-1.com"
    },
    {
      "@type":"ListItem",
      "position":2,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "image": "https://www.product-2.com/image",
        "URL": "https://www.product-2.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: These are restrictions Google add in relation to their rich results. I guess that restriction includes not linking to other domains.

Comment: Error with your JSON-LD (not related to your issue): Schema.org terms are case-sensitive. It must be `url` instead of `URL`.

Answer (score 3):

These errors are about Google’s [Carousels](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings) feature. This feature [requires](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings?hl=en#ItemList) certain `url` values:

- > If used on a summary page, all URLs in the list must point to different pages on the same domain.
- > If used on an all-in-one-page list, all URLs must point to the page hosting the list structured data.

Your case (linking to external sites) is simply not eligible for getting the Carousels feature in Google Search. You can (and should) keep your JSON-LD like this and ignore these errors in the SDTT.

Comment: It looks like "ItemList" isn't really the proper schema type in my case since no external URLs seem to be allowed in this schema type- https://www.screencast.com/t/6drskjDJd1Hc


I thought I could get a Google FS result like this for my article/blog page using the "ItemList" schema - https://www.screencast.com/t/OtLizWcPb (the page doesn't have any schema, the FS is generated by Google though)


Now, I'm just clueless as to what the proper schema type for a page that talks about 'top' products under a category with external URLs and images? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Iam_Amjath: No, as I said, your use of `ItemList` is perfectly fine. You just can’t get the Carousels feature in Google Search -- not because of your JSON-LD, but because of your content. -- The list in the search result snippet from your screenshot, as far as I know, isn’t the Carousels feature, and doesn’t necessarily come from `ItemList` markup (it might help, though).

Comment: Yes, that's not a carousel feature in the screenshot. It's just another featured snippet result in Google (without any markup on the page) in a larger window to help searchers.

I just wanted to help Google to create such a list for my article pages too, but the schema type I chose doesn’t seem to be the correct one.  So, with Google throwing errors in SDTT, I think adding the ItemList markup on my pages has the same effect as without it. Thank you for your help throughout!